# Keep only two rows corresponding to an ID in a data frame

Tags: r, subset

I have the following data (this is a mock version) and I am using R.

```
ID m
1  m1
1  m2
1  m3
2  m1
2  m2
3  m1
3  m2
3  m3
3  m4
4  m1
```

Each ID has an m1 row and the rest of the m's are of variable length amongst the ID's. I would like to keep the m1 value and the last value corresponding to each ID. The ideal output would look like this:

```
ID m
1  m1
1  m3
2  m1
2  m2
3  m1
3  m4
4  m1
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: OK. And what is your question? I expect you have done some research and at least some ideas about how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I only realized after posting that the question looked horrible.

Comment: As for my question, yes, I have done some research but I only got as far as being able to keep values which can be set to a certain string, however, my last value within an ID varies and I do not know how to keep those. Thanks.

Comment: @akrun no problem.. in fact I've just learned the `row_number` function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same result with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(row_number()==n()|m=='m1')


Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
Groups: ID

  ID  m
1  1 m1
2  1 m3
3  2 m1
4  2 m2
5  3 m1
6  3 m4
7  4 m1
```

Comment: @akrun I see. I try to fix that.

Comment: This also worked, thank you very much. I'll put in some effort into becoming an expert with dplyr, seems intuitive and extremely useful.

Comment: @Bogs the fix of Akrun is been necessary. Without it, I was still trying to figure out the problem. I am a very new R programmer and I understand what you are saying about intuitively of `dplyr` but when I'll be more proficient I'll try to learn `data.table` as well.

Answer (score 5):

One option would be using `data.table`

Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Grouped by 'ID' column, and based on a logical condition, we subset the dataset.  If the number of rows is 1 (`if(.N==1)`), we take the value of 'm' ie. the only value per group or `else`, we concatenate with the values that are 'm1' (`m[m=='m1']`) along with the last value of 'm' (`m[.N]`) per each group

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(m=if(.N==1) m else c(m[m=='m1'], m[.N])), by = ID]
#   ID  m
#1:  1 m1
#2:  1 m3
#3:  2 m1
#4:  2 m2
#5:  3 m1
#6:  3 m4
#7:  4 m1
```

Comment: that worked, thank you very much. Also, a special thank you for not getting snarky about my poor initial editing of the question.

Comment: @PierreLafortune  You can post that as a separate answer.    If the column is not ordered, wouldn't it give different result. i.e. the OP wants 'm1' as one of the values.

Comment: That is true, I corrected for the case of misplaced "m1" values.

Answer (score 5):

A `base` R solution:

```
df[ave(logical(nrow(df)),df$ID,FUN=function(x) seq_along(x) %in% c(1,length(x))),]
#   ID  m
#1   1 m1
#3   1 m3
#4   2 m1
#5   2 m2
#6   3 m1
#9   3 m4
#10  4 m1
```

Comment: Meravigliose queste soluzioni in base R.

Comment: @SabDeM Did you know I'm italian, or that's just a coincidence? :)

Comment: it's just a matter of statistics: I thought that 90% you were Italian due to the name "Nicola".

Comment: @SabDeM You are right! Anyway, thank you very much for the comment, much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Another `base R` way is with a split,apply,combine style filter:

```
`rownames<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df,df$ID), function(x) {
  x[x$m=="m1"|seq(nrow(x))==nrow(x),]})),NULL)
#   ID  m
# 1  1 m1
# 2  1 m3
# 3  2 m1
# 4  2 m2
# 5  3 m1
# 6  3 m4
# 7  4 m1
```

The core of the function is `x[x$m=="m1"|seq(nrow(x))==nrow(x),]`. Each group is subsetted by the column "m" values that are equal to "m1" or are the last row. All middle rows will be left out, as desired. `split(df,df$ID)` splits the data frame by ID. `do.call(rbind..` puts everything back together into one dataframe. And `'rownames<-'...,NULL)` makes the row numbers uniform.

Answer (score 3):

A bunch of base R one liners:

```
x[c(diff(x$ID),1) == 1 | c(1,diff(x$ID)) == 1, ]
x[(c(diff(x$ID),1) + c(1,diff(x$ID))) == 1, ]
x[x$m == 'm1' | c((x$m == 'm1')[-1],TRUE), ]
x[pmax(x$m == 'm1',c((x$m == 'm1')[-1],1)) == 1, ]
```